# .aux round-trip changing encoding?

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I have a situation where I write a simple string out to the aux:

```
\ifinlist{#1}\list
  {}
  {\listgadd\list{#1}%
   write to aux "\macro{#1}"}

\def\macro#1{\listgadd\list{#1}}
```

When the `\ifinlist` test comes round on the second run with `\list` populated via the `.aux` and `\macro`, the test always fails even though I can see with `\typeout` that the test should succeed. This only happens with elements which go via the `.aux`. Could there be some encoding issue here?

For example, here is the output of putting some typeouts in before and after the test block with `#1` coming from the .aux. As you can see, it's already in the list and is added again.

```
BEFORE:#1=sigfridsson,list=sigfridsson|companion|
AFTER:list=sigfridsson|companion|sigfridsson|
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide a complete MWE demonstrating the issue?  It is awful hard to work with code fragments, especially when dealing with multiple-pass compilation.

Comment: I was hoping someone might have seen something similar  ... it will take some time to construct a MWE as this is part of a large package.

Comment: Are you really using the name "\list"? Beside this if the string contains non-ascii chars then you will need `\unexpanded{\macro{stringäöü}}` when writing to the aux.

Comment: No, not really using `\list` and the strings are all ASCII so far which is why this is confusing.

Comment: Are you sure you are making the test *after* you did read the aux? Did you check the entry in the aux-file?

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly sure about that. I also tested it with adding the same thing to to the list twice *not* via the .aux and that works  ...

Comment: Well it is not easy to guess without example what could be wrong. Is the argument correct (#1 versus ##1 versus expanded/no expanded)? Btw: I guess you are working on the refsegment problem. Do you really need to avoid duplicates in the list? Also can't you record the entries in the bcf and let biber create some suitable list?

Comment: Yes, it's looking at the refsegment thing. I came across this strange behaviour when trying something and it does cause issues with bib filtering later. Doing it via the .bcf is a much bigger change (not only for refsegments) and it's not really necessary to involve biber. I'm trying to get a MWE to reproduce this.

Comment: macros are normally expanded when writing so if you write a macro (including accented letters) to an aux and read it back you would expect to get something that typesets the same way but not necessarily something that tests equal to `\ifinlist` (if I guess what that is doing)

Comment: that's what I assumed but it's all plain ascii. See the update.

Comment: Really the examples are too fragmented to guess what is happening, you need to make something that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I know, sorry, trying to do this.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this in a MWE yet but I can consistently get it to happen in context. There is a trace log of the pertinent bit here if someone had time to peruse it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/seizaugt9fjcglp/log.txt?dl=0

Comment: I can see where the macro goes wrong. But the only reason I can imagine is that the catcodes of the strings stored through the aux-file is different, e.g. if \detokenize were used. How is `\abx@aux@segm {\the \c@refsection }{\the \c@refsegment }{sigfridsson}` defined?

Comment: Just `\protected\def\abx@aux@segm#1#2#3{\listcsgadd{blx@segm@#1@#2{#3}}`

Comment: Could be a `\detokenize` somewhere on the way to the `.aux` I suppose - I'll have to check. I'll have to check the provenance of `#1`.

Comment: If you don't find it you can give me a biblatex.tds with the code and some complete example. (But please add @UlrikeFischer to your comment so that I get a ping.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - you were right, it was a `\detokenize` quite some distance from the manifesting location. If I `\detokenize` on the way in and out, it's ok. Please add an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see in the log-file where the macro goes wrong. It is obvious that `sigfridsson` is not equal to `sigfridsson`.

The only reason I can imagine for this behaviour is that the catcodes of the string stored through the aux-file are different than the catcodes of the string you are comparing it with. One possible cause could be that for one of the strings `\detokenize` is used.